# MapInfo Point Object Dialogue is different to Info Tool's Transformed XY

Tags: coordinate-system, mapinfo

A **MapInfo Professional 11.0.3** user has re-projected data from AGD84 Zone 50 to WGS 84. However when they **select a point** and look at the **point objects's X and Y**, they are **different** to what's reported in the Info Tools table. In all cases the Point Object is 360o by -90.0o. When I repeat the process in ArcGIS it works flawlessly: the data is defined, it transforms, and displays perfectly.

Why would a Point Object report incorrectly?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The info tool only displays the tabular data stored in the file. This is NOT linked to the spatial data so any changes to the spatial data may require an update of the tabular data in order for the two to agree.

In addition, check the projections of the session, map window, and table. You can ensure that the map window and session are using the same projection as the table by following the instructions below:

First, make the map window the front window, then open the MapBasic window (in the 'Tools' toolbar) and type in the following (replace `yourTableName` with the actual table name):

```
Set Map Window FrontWindow() Coordsys Table yourTableName
Set Coordsys Table yourTableName
```

Highlight both lines of code then hit Enter. You should now get your coordinates in the correct projection units.

You can also set your default projections under Options > Preferences > Map Window > Projection.

Comment: Ah Ha. I've checked the tabs projection and I'm not seeing WGS 84. Rather it has "CoordSys Earth Projection 1,0" with no parameters.

Comment: So how did they reproject the data?

Comment: This is a bug with Discover when re projecting a single point. When you use the "save as" tab method with a projection change .i.e. to WGS it works correctly. However when you use Discover to re project it does not re-project the data into the real world. (Discover 2011. Build 25).